# How to get microsoft office outlook web access?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, outlook-web-access

What are the steps to get Office Outlook Web Access in my system? I have Office Outlook only.

Can anybody say how to achive this?

1. Is there any product to achieve? Please provide detailed information.
2. Is there is any programming way to achieve this? Give me code with a small amount of explanation. I am an ASP.NET programmer in the C# language.

Comment: As I understand it, you need to set up an Exchange Server, &c.

Comment: You asked this question yesterday, please don't duplicate it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151917/how-to-use-outlook-web-access

Answer (score 3):

Buy Exchange.  OWA comes w/ it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 / 2007 has this built in, it just has to be set up correctly.

Head over to [ServerFault.com](http://www.ServerFault.com) and ask for help on setting it up there